# ¿Cómo separas un borde de un elemento cuando background-color lo rellena todo?

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de añadir a un elemento con un background-color un borde "espaciado". Lo explico mejor, en html tenngo esto:

```
<div></div>
```

Luego en CSS:

```
div{
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Lo que quiero es que al hacer click en mi elemento aparezca un borde separado del elemento y no pegado a mi elemento:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("div").onclick = 
 document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.border= "2px dashed red";
```

Se que esto no sirve porque tengo el background-color y rellena el padding. Entonces la questión es ¿hay alguna manera de añadir un color de fondo que no sea usando background-color o que no rellene el padding? Y si no la hay, ¿tienen alguna idea de como separar el elemento del borde y que siga coloreado? Un gracias adelantado!

```js
document.querySelector("div").onclick = 
document.querySelector("div").style.border = "2px dashed red";
```

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de ocupar border, puedes ocupar "outline" este te coloca ese "borde" por  fuera. Además, tiene la propiedad "outline-offset con la cual puedes añadir mayor separación, o incluso colocar el borde por dentro si es que le colocas un valor negativo

```js
document.querySelector("div").onclick = function()
{
    this.style.outline = "2px dashed red";
    this.style.outlineOffset= "2px";
};
```

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```